# Combining images in rectangle, if i hide rectangle, images should be hidden too

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, layout

I am using a rectangle and putting emotion images in it, and i want to do  is if I make the rectangle hidden, the emotion images in it should be hidden.
I am attaching an image for help in it.
[image]

Please let me know which property should I use for getting this, in Windows Forms if we use panel, this can be done automatically. But in WPF C#, this is not done automatically.

Here is the code

```
<Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="226,262,0,0" Name="rectangle2" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Fill="#B5101010" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,266,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_evilgrin.png" MouseUp="image1_MouseUp_1" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="264,266,0,0" Name="image2" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_grin.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" MouseUp="image2_MouseUp" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,299,0,0" Name="image4" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_tongue.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Grid.Column="1" MouseUp="image4_MouseUp" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,266,0,0" Name="image5" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_suprised.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Grid.Column="1" MouseUp="image5_MouseUp" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,266,0,0" Name="image6" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_smile.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Grid.Column="1" MouseUp="image6_MouseUp" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,266,0,0" Name="image7" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_happy.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Grid.Column="1" MouseUp="image7_MouseUp" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,299,0,0" Name="image8" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_wink.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Grid.Column="1" MouseUp="image8_MouseUp" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,299,0,0" Name="image9" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_unhappy.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" MouseUp="image9_MouseUp" Visibility="Hidden" />
<Image Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,299,0,0" Name="image10" Source="/WPFTEST;component/Images/emo/emotion_waii.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" MouseUp="image10_MouseUp" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

I know that it is not under the rectangle tag, but if i add images under rectangle tag then it causes error.

Thanks
Atif

Comment: I have edited my problem again.

Comment: I can see from miles away that this code was generated by one of those forsaken GUI-designers, the redundancy and unreadability is rather stunning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those icons are part of the "rectangle" which should be an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) or panel of some sort, the icons *will* hide if the parent container is hidden ([`Visibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx) = [`Visibility.Hidden/Collapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx)).

**Edit:** The images are not part of the rectangle they are just placed on top using horrible margin abusing code.

There is no relationship between the rectangle and the icons. As i said, the icons need to be added as children of a container. (e.g. [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) with [`WrapPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) as [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx)) Surely winforms would not hide the icons either if they are not part of an owning container...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave your code as is and not have to change those margins you can just bind the Visibility property of the icons to the Visibility property of the rectangle.

Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=rectangle2}"